# I locked my 4 kittens in a room to get them used to using a litter box, they have food and water

Tags: cats, toilet-training

My cat gave birth to 4 kittens almost 2 months ago. We used to have their litter box near where their mom wanted them to be but after a while the mother too started to pee in that litter box and the smell was really bad so we took them down to the garage. The garage is clean and empty and since they're there we don't open it and park our cars outside. We try to keep the mother with them but she doesn't want to stay in the garage and she doesn't want them to stay in the garage either. We would let them into the house every couple of hours but they would pee/poop somewhere so we would collect them and put them in the garage again. They would start scratching the door and meowing. They have water and food. I feel so guilty but they pee everywhere and I'm always following them around the house to make sure they don't pee anywhere and sometimes they still do. Can someone please help me!! I really don't how to deal with this.

Comment: Could you rephrase? "she doesn't want to stay in the garage and she doesn't want to stay in the garage either" is just repeating twice the same thing?

Comment: (and Welcome to Pets SE! Read the https://pets.stackexchange.com/tour to know which questions to ask and how, and to win a badge!)

Answer (score 4):

If the litter box stinks, it needs to be cleaned! Imagine how unpleasant it would be for you to have to use a stinky and dirty toilet. So the first step to get your kittens to use their litter box is to clean it several times each day. Removing the clumbs should suffice most days. When it starts stinking, you should empty it and rinse it with water and some dishwashing liquid.

The rule of thumb for multi-pet households is to provide one litter box for each cat plus one extra. That is probably overkill for 4 kittens, but you get the idea: when one box is used and the kittens search for an alternative, having one more box is better than having them pee in a corner. If you let them back into the house, keep them in a limited space (like 1 - 2 rooms) and put several litter boxes in there.

Some kittens also need supervision for a while. Whenever you see one kitten pee or poop outside of a litter box, immediately lift it up and put it in a litter box as quickly as possible. Don't scold or punish the kitten in any way or it might never learn to use the litter box properly.
You should also clean the old pee spots with a special enzymatic cleaner. If the kittens smell old pee they assume that this is the correct spot to pee again. You can find cat urine with a UV flashlight.

The type of litter boxes can also be a problem. How high is the edge of your current box? If it's too hard for the kittens to climb into he box, they won't want to use it. Some cats also dislike litter boxes with a lid.

And lastly, what type of cat litter do you use? Coarse grain litter might be uncomfortable for tiny kitten paws. You can try different types of litter in different litter boxes and see which one your kittens like best.

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for your reply!! They have two litter boxes and we clean them every day.